# Which C function can convert À, É to lower à, è?

Tags: c, locale, lowercase, tolower

Which C function can convert À, É to lower à, è?

I tried tolower() and towlower(), but both do not work.

Comment: Don't spam tags for unrelated languages. C is not C++ is not C.

Comment: Why not write you own? Couple of lines of code

Comment: `X do not work` is of less use here. Post relevant code.

Comment: add 32 to the underlying integral value. I can show you how to if you paste a sample of the code you're using.

Comment: The reason `towlower` probably wasn't working is that you did not unset the locale which was probably set to `en_US` (just a guess). See my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [towlower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towlower) function:

```
/* towlower example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main () {

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    int i=0;
    wchar_t str[] = L"À TÉst String.\n";
    wchar_t c;
    while (str[i]) {
        c = str[i];
        putwchar (towlower(c));
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output is:

```
à tést string.
```

> [> A C program inherits its locale environment variables when it starts
>   
> > up. This happens automatically. However, these variables do not
>   
> > automatically control the locale used by the library functions,
>   
> > because ANSI C says that all programs start by default in the standard
>   
> > `C' locale. To use the locales specified by the environment, you must
>   
> > call setlocale. Call it as follows:
>   
> > 
>   
> > setlocale (LC_ALL, "");](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_19.html#SEC323)

**""**
    The empty name says to select a locale based on environment variables.

Comment: Notice the `w` in the name of this function!  This is one of the "alternative functions" that I was speaking-of in my Answer.

Comment: The important part of the answer is setlocale. Having adjusted the locale, even tolower might work well, provided the strings are in the correct encoding (for French probably ISO-8559-15, on Windows possibly CP-1252). Unfortunately, we do not know there the strings to be change come from (file, console, source code - the latter: joining Ed's comment...). With utf8, we are out anyway...

Comment: For utf-8 encoded strings, I would have a look at the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library.

Comment: Hi khredos, thanks, it works after add 'setlocale()'.

Answer (score 1):

The *actual* problem that you are facing here *(despite the preceding "Answers"), is that you have a **Unicode** string. *(Or, at the very least, some kind of DBCS = "Double-Byte Character Set.")

The standard functions of the ***"C"*** language were devised "in a much-earlier, much-simpler time," in which the only language-representation that needed to be considered was `ASCII`, which assigned "every character that needed to be represented" into a set of 127 possible values. *Nowhere* in this picture were any "diacritical markings" such as these. In those simple times, "1 byte = 1 character."

In order to represent "real *human(!)*-language characters," it was necessary to adopt a far more flexible encoding format which might assign anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes to a single "character." *(And, mind you, a consensus about "exactly how to do this" did not happen overnight!)* In any case, the "original" library-routines that you are now using here are not "Unicode aware." *(They never were designed to be, and they cannot now be retrofitted ...)* Instead, alternate functions must be used.

Here's a good external web-page which gives a pretty good summary of the various issues that need to be considered when using C and C++:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html

--- **Edit:**
When I said, "a consensus about exactly how to do this did not happen overnight," my comment was intended to have potentially far-reaching(!) implications. *"Why is it necessary, even today, to say `"encoding=UTF-8"`?* This is why. *"A single interpretation of 'how to interpret a multi-national sequence-of-bytes'"* never did develop, and the "C" language, especially, "took it in the chin." There are more-than-one complete sets of library-functions in today's "C" runtime that you might need to use, in order to correctly handle *your* data.

Comment: Nah, it could be a single-byte encoding like Windows-1252. The OP should probably specify their encoding.